# getContentResolver().query(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI returns null

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-contentresolver

getContentResolver().query(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI returns null While trying to query for browser history.

Explicitly, this returns null:

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION, null, null, Browser.BookmarkColumns.DATE + " DESC");
```

When permission is noted:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS" />
```

And called from the main activity.

This started happening after the latest chrome update.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue if the query is done before Chrome browser is started.  Once I launch Chrome, and return to my app, the query works.

The bug being discussed here may be related:
   https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=497538

If this bug is the cause, then it looks like a fix is in progress.